# no parameter binding found for name (Spring data jpa)

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have two entities like A and B such that:

```
 class B {
    private Integer id;
    private String field1;
    private String field2;
    // getters and setters   
 }

 class A {
    private Date date;
    //one to one mapping is there between A and B
    private B b;
    //getters and setters
 }
```

I have a spring data repository such that:

```
 @Query("from A a where a.date= :date and a.b.id =:#{#b.id}")
        A findByBAndDate(@Param(value = "date") Date date,@Param(value = "b") B b);
```

But I am getting the exception, `no parameter binding found for name b!`.

However, if I modify the above query as:

```
@Query("from A a where a.b.id =:#{#b.id}")
A findByB(@Param(value = "b") B b);
```

all works fine. What's the issue with this.

Answer (score 29):

It seems that we must use SPeL for all parameters in the query, not mixing jpa ways and SPel : `:date` mixed with `:#{#b.id}`.

Try this, I have not tested I don't know how it would behave with a `Date` :

```
 @Query("from A a where a.date= :#{#date} and a.b.id =:#{#b.id}")
        A findByBAndDate(@Param(value = "date") Date date,@Param(value = "b") B b);
```

Comment: Thanks! Saved me tons of time. It would be great if this shall be mentioned somewhere in the official documentation!

Comment: Looks like this might've been [fixed in Spring Data JPA 2.0 RC1](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-1140), with an example usage [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/sample/UserRepository.java#L477)